# Create a non clickable MenuItem with multiple text lines

Tags: java, android, menu

I'd like to add an Item in the Menu of my App to display the version number of the app.

Of course the item should **not** be clickable.

And I really don't know how to do that.

I tried with "Appname\nVersion" but it does not work (just display the \n). And I could find any option to disable the click on the item.

Even if the item is disabled I can click it...

Any idea?

My code:

```
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());

    MenuItem appVersion = popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.appVersion);
    appVersion.setTitle(String.format(getString(R.string.appVersion), BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME));

    popup.show();
```

My menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/manageMaps"
        android:title="@string/manageMaps" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/appVersion"
        android:title="@string/appVersion" />
    <item android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:title="@string/exit" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_item);
item.setVisible(true);
item.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Tried right now: no changes... And any idea how to write the text in two lines?